# Question regarding "this" inside anonymous function of prototype.js .each method

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I've been searching for hours for a solution to this problem. I'm creating a table using prototype.js 1.6.0.1 and am having trouble with the this object in context with the .each function. here is a snippit.

```
var Table = Class.create({
  initialize : function(id) {
    this.elmnt = $(id);
    this.rows = [];
  },
  initRows : function() {
    $A(this._elmnt.tBodies).each(function(body) {
      $A(body.rows).each(function(row) {
        //right here is where i would like to call
        // this.rows.push(row);
        console.log(this); // prints DOMWindow
      });
    });
  }
});
```

As you can see inside the second .each function this resolves to DOMWindow. I would like to be able to call `this.rows.push(row)` but I can't as "this" isn't resolving as expected.

Any help would be appreciated. I know i could do the standard (i=0; i < length; i++) loop but I was trying to make this a little cleaner. Thanks for any guidance you can offer.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to maintain a collection of rows in your `Table` object? A `HTMLTableElement` already maintains its own collection. `this.elmnt.rows` or `this.elmnt.tBodies[0].rows`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/table.rows

Comment: This is why I don't like `each()` implementations that override `this`.  And why I love coffee script and it's non scope introducing and non context raping array iteration.

Comment: We are maintaining a collection of rows for easy manipulation. we aren't worried about the size of the collection because it never gets too large, always less than 25 rows and the default is around 10 i belive. I also can't go with coffee script because I can't introduce any new tools into our stack (this is all in a rails 2.3.5  application)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to work around this is to save `this` at the start of `initRows` and refer to in within the `each` functions

```
initRows : function() {
    var self = this;
    $A(this._elmnt.tBodies).each(function(body) {
      $A(body.rows).each(function(row) {
        //right here is where i would like to call
        self.rows.push(row);
        console.log(self); // prints DOMWindow
      });
    });
  }
```

The problem you're running into is that `this` can be manipulated by the caller of the function.  It's very common in callbacks to set `this` to an element which is relevant to the call back.  In the case of `each` it's set to the element for the current iteration of the value.

The `self` trick works because it saves the `this` as it's bound in the function `initRows` and then uses that saved value in the iteration.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. That's a good thing to know if I run into this again. Not thrilled about the var self = this but it's a much better solution than the good old fashioned for loop w/ indexes;

Comment: @grizzgreen: If you don't like the variable, [use Prototypejs's `.bind()` method](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Function/prototype/bind/) instead.

Comment: +1 for a good explanation of *this* without confusing it with scope or context. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
initRows : function() {
    $A(this._elmnt.tBodies).each(function(body) {
        $A(body.rows).each((function(e, row) {
            e.rows.push(row);
            console.log(e);
        }).bindAsEventListener(this, row));
    });
}
```

Comment: I disagree with this. The callback for each is not an event so does not need to be `bindAsEventListener()`, even `bind()` is overkill since the second parameter of [`each()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Enumerable/prototype/each/) is the context. At the point where it is bound `row` does not exist so it cannot be curried, `row` only exists _inside_ the callback. Even though you try to bind a context for the callback you don't make an example of using `this` within it. The parameters for the callback are wrong, it should be `(row, index)` where `index` is optional.